# Dispatch Table in C++

Tags: c++, c, dispatch-table

Suppose I have something like the following:

```
class Point : geometry {
   ...
   Point(double x, double y) {
   }
   double distanceTo(Line) {
   }
   double distanceTo(Point) {
   }
}
class Line : geometry {
   ...
   Line(double x, double y, double slopex, double slopey) {
   }
   double distanceTo(Line) {
   }
   double distanceTo(Point) {
   }
}
struct point_t {
    double x, y;
}
struct line_t {
    double x, y, slope_x, slope_y;
}
struct Geom_Object_t {
   int type;
   union {
       point_t p;
       line_t l;
   } geom;
}
```

I am wondering what the best way to define a dispatch table for a function like

```
double distanceTo(Geom_Object_t * geom1, Geom_Object_t * geom2) {
}
```

The classes are written in C++, but the distanceTo function and the struct must be externed to C

thanks

Comment: There *is* no portable way to "extern to C" a `struct` that includes a `union` among classes which are **not** Plain-Old-Data (and Point and Line aren't, as they have method overloads). If you want a non-portable solution for some specific proprietary C++ compiler, mention that; otherwise, rethink your ill-conceived constraints, because what you ask (if the requirement is to be standards compliant and portable) is simply not feasible -- so you may have to use for C purposes e.g. a struct with a _pointer_ (and cast/deref that pointer in the C++ code), that _would_ be OK.

Comment: @Alex Marelli sorry about that, fixed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would make the class diagram different: an abstract base class `GeomObject`, subclassing `geometry` (with a `getType` accessor, as well as pure virtual `distanceTo` overloads), and concrete subclasses `Line` and `Point` of `GeomObject` (with overrides of the accessor and overloads).  The need to `"extern C"` the `double distanceTo` function is not a problem, since you're not talking about overloads *of that function* anyway: you simply want to return `geom1.distanceTo(x)` (letting the virtual table do that part of the work;-) where `x` is an appropriate cast, e.g., assuming the class diagram I've explained:

```
extern "C"
double distanceTo(Geom_Object_t * geom1, Geom_Object_t * geom2) {
  if(geom2->getType() == POINT_TYPE) {
    return geom1->distanceTo(static_cast<Point*>(geom2));
  } else {
    return geom1->distanceTo(static_cast<Line*>(geom2));
  }
}
```

Comment: the struct can no longer be used from C, however.

Comment: @adk, no, but you said only the `distanceTo` function needed to be `"extern C"`!

Comment: @adk, yep, and with you "clarification" it becomes clear that your original solution also breaks your constraints -- to "extern C" a struct, it has to be a "plain-old-data" one, so in particular no union with classes of which one or more have overloaded methods... externing **that** to C is not standard/portable. So rethink your constraints or add a level of indirectness via a pointer (which would make my answer be fully `"extern C"`able just as well of course;-).

Comment: @Alex Martelli  sorry about that fixed.

Comment: @adk, so now you just need to **build** a `Point` or `Line` as needed (depending on `type`) for each operand, my answer still applies when you do that (just call the abstract base class `Foobar` since you completely redefined the meaning of the arguments' pointed-to class, `Geom_object_t` -- do you need me to spell that out, really?-)

Answer (score 2):

I would use [double dispatch with Visitor pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern). Then you only have to have two pointers to `geometry` objects and let double dispatch call the appropriate virtual `distanceTo` function based on actual dynamic types of two objects, which you can do from your C function.

Answer (score 1):

*(updated to match updated question)*

To avoid duplication move your conversion code in one helper function and let C++ do the rest of the work:

```
geometry makeg(Geom_Object_t* g) {
    switch(g->type) {
         case TYPE_POINT: return Point(g->geom.p.x, g->geom.p.y);
         case TYPE_LINE : return Line(g->geom.l.x, g->geom.l.y, g->geom.l.slope_x, g->geom.l.slope_y);
         // ...
    }
}

makeg(geom1).distanceTo(makeg(geom2));
```

Answer (score 0):

could you do something simple like:

```
if (g1->type == LINE) {
  if (g2->type == LINE) return g1->distance(g2->l);
  if (g2->type == POINT) ...
}
else ...
```

you can implement this part in C++ and expose the function through the extern "C"

then you could perhaps provide a method in your geometrical classes to accept geometrical struct as a parameter and perform dispatching inside the classes using regular C++ function overload.

Comment: Not if you have 10 different types, and 20 methods for each

Comment: @adk, no, but by letting C++ pick the right override, as in my answer, it's an `O(M)` problem in terms of code size (best if `M <= N`, of course, but how do you ever end up with `M != N` when the methods' overloads should obviously be one per type?!).